# AUTORUN.INF : The style of the INF is different than what was requested

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-7

I though the following task would be fairly simple and straightforward, but that isn't turning out to be the case.  Situation: I have a WMV file that I burned to a DVD along with an AUTORUN.INF file.  The AUTORUN.INF file has the following contents:

```
[autorun]
open=mymovie.wmv
```

When I insert the DVD into my Windows 8 PC, I then open MY COMPUTER and double click on drive D (my DVD drive), I get the following error message: This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.

[image: Error]

If I right mouse click on Drive D, and choose "Open Autoplay", the Autoplay window will appear. I am then asked what would I like to do with the disc. I choose "Run mymovie.wmv". When I do this, I get the same error message as above.

If I right mouse click on Drive D, and choose "Open", and right mouse click on the AUTORUN.INF file, and choose INSTALL, I get the error message below:

[image: Error]

If I simply double click the WMV file, Windows Media Player launches and begins playing the video.

So what's going on here?

When I try the same exercise on my Windows 7 PC, I the AUTORUN.INF file is likewise ignored. Double clicking on the Drive D from MY COMPUTER gives me the error: "D:\ is not a valid Win32 application."

Below are the AutoPlay options from the Windows 8 machine:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a .wmv file is - as far as the system is concerned - meaningless. The system can only open executable files. What you want is to find an associated application an launch that instead:

To do so, don't use the [`open` [AutoRun] key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200.aspx#open). Instead, go with the [`shellexecute` [AutoRun] key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200.aspx#Shellexecute). This determines the application associated with a media file and launches that application.